# Handle BigQuery error from the querying by using Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, python-bigquery

To handle the errors from bigquery I have used - `job.errors[0]['message']` and everything was fine so far.

The issue is when you querying and for example, when you divide the value by 0, BigQuery will show you:

[image]

QUESTION: By using PYTHON - HOW to pick up this error?

Answer (score 0):

Or, in BigQuery Standard SQL, you can use SAFE_DIVIDE() to avoid error

SAFE_DIVIDE() is equivalent to the division operator (/), but returns NULL if an error occurs, such as a division by zero error

So instead of `SELECT 15 / 0`  you should use `SAFE_DIVIDE(15, 0)`

Comment: I understand how to avoided ))) This is was just as an example) Question if more about HOW to handle the errors when you querying

Comment: i see. so this is more python related and not bigquery I think